# How can I bind a date from ng-model to an HTML 5 date input?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind a date from my model to an HTML 5 date input like this:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="data.employeeCase.initialConsultDate" />
```

The property looks like this in my JSON:

```
"initialConsultDate": "2017-04-20T04:00:00",
```

I can get it to set by hard coding like this:

```
<input type="date" value="2017-04-20">
```

How do I set I like that using the value from my model and bind it using ng-model?

**UPDATE 1:**
Answer 1 below worked for me.

I just wanted to show my implementation in case anyone has trouble.

```
    /***** Get Employee Case By ID *****/
    $scope.getEmployeeCase = function (caseId) {
        //console.log("In GetEmployeeCase");
        //console.log(caseUrl + '/' + caseId);
        $http.get(caseUrl + '/' + caseId)
           .then(function (response) {
               // Test front end exception message;
               // throw "test exception";
               $scope.data.employeeCase = response.data;

               var date = new Date(response.data.initialConsultDate);
               $scope.sanitizedInitialConsultDate = $filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd")
                              })
           .catch(function (error) {
               $scope.data.caseDetailError = error;
               $scope.data.error = error;
           });
    }

<th>Intitial Consult Date:</th>
    <td>
        <input type="date" ng-value="sanitizedInitialConsultDate" ng-model="data.employeeCase.initialConsultDate" />
    </td>
```

Comment: did you follow the advice in the error message that angular presents?  https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-04-20T04:00:00.  In other words, `initialConsultDate` needs to be a `Date`, not a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the date string from the json and create a `new Date()`. Then, use Angular's `$filter` service to format the date as you see fit.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {

 var json = {
  initialConsultDate: "2017-04-20T04:00:00"
 };

 var date = new Date(json.initialConsultDate);

 $scope.date = $filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");


});
```

Then, use `ng-value` to set your date input:

`<input type="date" ng-value="date">`

Demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/UEcWvpyO1df4SXhvdNla?p=preview

Comment: Works like a charm:) Thank you.